# C# Make application compatible on other computers?

Tags: c#

EDIT: here is the file if someone want to test:
[Cleaner](http://speedy.sh/dHV54/OSO.exe)

I'm making a program that cleans some files automatically at startup for performance reasons.

How do I make an application work on another computer that only has the release files?

I made the Application using Framework 2.0 and works correctly without errors on my computer but if I copy the release files to another computer, "Application stopped responding" happens when it starts.

There is no resource files except from Icon and is embedded resource.
I have no Idea what to do.

```
    private void Cleansystem()
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
        String Offline = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SYSTEMROOT%") + "\\Offline Web Pages";
        String download = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SYSTEMROOT%") + "\\Downloaded Program Files";
        String software = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SYSTEMROOT%") + "\\SoftwareDistribution\\Download";
        String wintemp = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SYSTEMROOT%") + "\\Temp";
        String recent = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%appdata%") + "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Recent";
        String cookies = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%appdata%") + "\\Microsoft\\Windows\\cookies";
        String TempInternet = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%") + "\\Local Settings\\Temporary Internet Files";
        String apptemp = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%") + "\\appdata\\Local\\Temp";
        String settingtemp = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%") + "\\Local Settings\\Temp";
        EmptyFolderContents(Offline);
        EmptyFolderContents(download);
        EmptyFolderContents(software);
        EmptyFolderContents(wintemp);
        EmptyFolderContents(recent);
        EmptyFolderContents(cookies);
        EmptyFolderContents(TempInternet);
        EmptyFolderContents(apptemp);
        EmptyFolderContents(settingtemp);
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    private void EmptyFolderContents(string folderName)
    {
        foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folderName))
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.Delete(folder, true);
            }
            catch (Exception excep)
            {
                logger.Fatal(excep);
            }
        }
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folderName))
        {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
    catch (Exception excep)
    {
      logger.Fatal(excep);
    }
        }
    }
    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressBar1.Value != 10)
        {
            progressBar1.Value++;
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

> 2013-05-08 18:02:58.7013 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file
>   'C:\Windows\Temp\Cleaner.vsho_130508_173905_05efe1ff-6b41-4cb6-bb00-7acad6960c36.iTrace'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:58.7349 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file
>   'C:\Windows\Temp\OSO.vshost.exe_130508_174608_0d66d9df-040c-457b-84b5-7c3576196718.iTrace'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:58.8630 FATAL System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path 'Aug2005_d3dx9_27_x64.cab' is denied.    at
>   System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath,
>   Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String
>   path, Boolean recursive)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 912
>   2013-05-08 18:02:58.8743 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\appdata\Local\Temp\etilqs_2Isw34P5eLyyP6D'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:58.9074 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\appdata\Local\Temp\etilqs_7CSWlOdfR5GbUuD'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:58.9279 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\appdata\Local\Temp\etilqs_9htGcbvUEEpPsK3'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:58.9389 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\appdata\Local\Temp\etilqs_fPoiWPUjDlCkgey'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:58.9703 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Administrator\appdata\Local\Temp\etilqs_JtJ95QHTNu6Vj7D'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:59.0947 FATAL System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path 'Aug2005_d3dx9_27_x64.cab' is denied.    at
>   System.IO.Directory.DeleteHelper(String fullPath, String userPath,
>   Boolean recursive, Boolean throwOnTopLevelDirectoryNotFound)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.Delete(String fullPath, String userPath, Boolean
>   recursive, Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.Directory.Delete(String
>   path, Boolean recursive)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 912
>   2013-05-08 18:02:59.1152 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Temp\etilqs_2Isw34P5eLyyP6D' because it is being used by
>   another process.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,
>   String maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path,
>   Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:59.1263 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Temp\etilqs_7CSWlOdfR5GbUuD' because it is being used by
>   another process.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,
>   String maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path,
>   Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:59.1563 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Temp\etilqs_9htGcbvUEEpPsK3' because it is being used by
>   another process.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,
>   String maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path,
>   Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:59.1774 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Temp\etilqs_fPoiWPUjDlCkgey' because it is being used by
>   another process.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,
>   String maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path,
>   Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923
>   2013-05-08 18:02:59.1886 FATAL System.IO.IOException: The process
>   cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Administrator\Local
>   Settings\Temp\etilqs_JtJ95QHTNu6Vj7D' because it is being used by
>   another process.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode,
>   String maybeFullPath)    at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path,
>   Boolean checkHost)    at System.IO.File.Delete(String path)    at
>   GifImagee.MainWindow.EmptyFolderContents(String folderName) in
>   c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tet\Cleaner\Cleaner\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 923

Comment: "Application stopped responding" could be anything.  An infinite loop would cause it.  Compatibility is probably not the problem.

Comment: Not quite sure what is happening with your application. Do you have any code? A computer with .NET 2.0 installed should run your application just fine unless it depends on other libraries.

Comment: @RobertHarvey
Can It be that if some files can't be deleted program crashes on other computers?

Comment: Why don't you post the relevant code?

Comment: Add some logging to your program to see how far it gets before it fails.

Comment: This could be a huge number of things. The first thing I'd check is whether you're making assumptions about folder structure and access permissions that aren't true on the other machine. Can you connect a debugger to it on the other computer to see exactly where it gets stuck? Or get it to write to a log?

Comment: @Steve
"Why don't you post the relevant code?"
Doing it right away.

Comment: @mbeckish
"Add some logging to your program to see how far it gets before it fails."
There is no log file on other computers because of the crash. The log doesn't have the chance to initialize the logging.

Comment: Empty `catch` blocks should be a court-martial offence...

Comment: Add an appropriate message in your catch. In this way if an error occurs you never know.

Comment: As mentioned by others, log your errors and never use empty catch blocks. If you can install visual studio and run the application in debug mode on the other computer you'll find out whats wrong. As a MUCH better alternative get to grips with log4net - you are blind without logging - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial

Comment: Alright here is the log from my computer.
See updated description

Comment: @CountZero
I have Logging installed, check new description for catch and log errors

Comment: Try to use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to robustly combine paths and filenames. In fact, all members of `Path` are useful for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to change your code in this way

```
private void EmptyFolderContents(string folderName)
{
    if(Directory.Exists(folderName)
    {
        foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folderName))
        {
            try
            {
                Directory.Delete(folder, true);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)                
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Error deleting folder: " + folder+ Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(folderName))
        {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Error deleting file: " + file + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

}

I have added the minimal check to see if the directory exists, but keep in mind that this code could fail for a very large number of reasons. [Look at the exceptions list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) on the MSDN documentation

Comment: Seems like I have to use built in CMD solution then?

Thanks for help... :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the "Event Viewer" to see if there are more details there.  Perhaps there is a configuration file missing or a permissions issue being hit.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one of the files is locked - which is usual for temp files which I imagine are what you are trying to delete.

This should not be causing your issue as the delete is in a try catch, to be honest - in your case it may be best to have an empty try catch.

See here.

[Detecting whether a file is locked by another process (or indeed the same process)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424830/detecting-whether-a-file-is-locked-by-another-process-or-indeed-the-same-proces)

There is a security exception when you try to access the following folder  'Aug2005_d3dx9_27_x64.cab'  you get a 'FATAL System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path x' error.

Try wrapping your 'foreach (var folder in Directory.GetDirectories(folderName))' block in a try catch, update the folder permissions, exclude the problematic folders from your delete or check for permissions on folders before you try to access them.